# How can i define a structure with a string?

Tags: c#, string, xna-4.0

I have

```
public string[] ButtonList()
{
    string[] buttons = { "A", "B", "Back", "BigButton", "etc..." }
    return buttons;
}

private void EchoButtons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ButtonList().Length; i++)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            // Echo the buttons
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway i could use the string from the array to define the button? 
Example (although this does't work):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ButtonList().Length; i++)
{
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.ButtonList()[i] == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        // Echo the buttons
    }
}
```

Edit: i hope this makes sense, i wasn't sure i explained it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list of delegates which have `GamePadState` as a parameter, and return the state for the desired buttons.

```
var getButtonState = new List<Func<GamePadState, ButtonState>>
{
    s => s.Buttons.A,
    s => s.Buttons.B,
    ...
};

// Example to get the state of the first item in the list.
ButtonState state = getButtonState[0]( GamePad.GetState( PlayerIndex.One ) );
```